Applying KVL in op amp with floating source

From my understanding, the solution first applies the summing point constraint even though there is no ground on the non-inverting input, leading to 0V on both inputs. But how do they apply KVL across the inverting and non-inverting inputs, for both loops 1 and 2? Are you allowed to jump between wires when applying KVL for a known voltage between the wires? How else would you form the closed loops 1 and 2 to apply KVL? For example, in loop 1, how do they go from the top resistor to the bottom resistor in that loop?
This question is different from what I asked in "Is it correct to apply KVL through the 2 inputs of an op amp?" because the solution from the previous question does not apply to this one since I cannot use equal voltages to apply KVL across a closed loop in this question. I did not actually have to jump between wires in the previous question. But I do not see how that can be avoided here.


This question is similar to: Is it correct to apply KVL through the 2 inputs of an op amp?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I understand that my phrasing is similar, but the solution from the previous question does not apply to this one since I cannot use equal voltages to apply KVL across a closed loop in this question. I did not actually have to jump between wires in the previous question. But I do not see how that can be avoided here.

It's not clear that $V_{INV}=V_{NONINV}$ for this arrangement, because there's positive feedback present too, for the upper op-amp. However, if you can show that this op-amp's $V_{INV}$ changes faster than $V_{NONINV}$ for some change in op-amp $V_{OUT}$, then negative feedback is dominant, and the assumption $V_{INV}=V_{NONINV}$ will be true. That's not immediately evident, though, and would require more detailed analysis.

This is an enhanced Howland current generator ...

"...I did not actually have to jump between wires in the previous question. But I do not see how that can be avoided here..." Jumping between wires is an incorrect visualization.  Please see my answer to your previous question

You can also add the opamp equation ... (Up - Um)*Gain=Uout ... And make Gain=infinity.
